# Banned from asking questions and cannot correct

Tags: support

I have been banned from asking questions on stack overflow and cannot fix this because the question was closed so I cannot alter it to get positive votes

Comment: yes you can alter it.

Comment: Why cant you edit a closed question? Closing a question is not permanent and does not prevent editing. If you improve the question, people may try to re-open it.

Comment: It's a question that was too localised so people probably won't see it even though its been edited

Comment: Have you ever deleted any questions?

Comment: Yea but not in a good 7-8 months as I haven't logged in

Comment: Well, your profile doesn't look that bad to me, but deleted questions do count against you according to the banning algorithm.

Comment: So there's nothing I can do?

Comment: @Jamesp1989 (significant) Edits bump the question on the front page. Specifically for closed questions, they also put them in a re-open review queue that's available to higher rep users (3K+). So, if you can think of any way of improving your question, go for it, a single good edit is usually enough to get a fair bit of new attention to it.

Comment: And assuming [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15619508/99456) is the question that triggered the ban, it shouldn't have been downvoted and it should probably be re-opened. It's not too localized, you stumbled upon a mismatch between different PHP versions. Give it a better title (unless someone is having issues with line 25, they won't find it), fix the grammar (capitalize your Is please) and make the text a bit more descriptive, and I can see it getting upvoted and re-opened.

Comment: Yea that's the question I posted shortly before the ban. People seem to down-vote without thinking

Comment: @Jamesp1989: rather than blame downvoters, it's a good idea to consider how you can improve future questions (as noted by others, putting a line number in the title makes it too localized to your situation). Furthermore, especially if English is your native language, you should put more effort into grammar and syntax (people tend to down vote questions that seem unprofessional). I upvoted and voted to reopen your question, and along with other reopen votes it is no longer closed.

Answer (score 3):

Unless there's some aspect to this that I don't know about, you **can** edit your closed questions.

Just click the `edit` button

Answer (score 1):

There is an `edit` link next to share.
You can click on to edit your post.